# MissingServletRequestParameterException: requird parameter not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/connect{accountDeviceId}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody
String showCompleteAuthorizat(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam("accountDeviceId") int accountDeviceId) throws Exception {
```

I'm getting this error

```
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required int parameter 'accountDeviceId' is not present
```

and this is the url that calls the above api

```
http://localhost:8080/gch-restful/fitbit/connect29?oauth_token=b1e939450e745664ce4bbbc194b4ed47f&oauth_verifier=9dc1045654dc775d2347ae2963d5ae878c
```

I'm new to spring and basically learning it, please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `@PathVariable(value="accountDeviceId")`  instead of `@RequestParam("accountDeviceId")` in order to get a variable from url.